# Create new mongoose document without copying entire schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, feathersjs

I have a mongoose question that I'll try to form into something that makes sense. So, I have a User schema with a LOT of stuff in it.

Is there a way to create a new user without copying the entire schema in another file? So, just reference the schema and pass through values that are changed?

In past projects, everything in my schema also needed to be updated when creating users so that wasn't an issue.

Comment: Like extending user schema to a new type of user?

Comment: @Sridhar No new types, just creating a new user period but using the schema I've created.

Comment: "without copying the entire schema" Can you elaborate a little on this? If you want to leave out a few fields in the schema, you can do so. Only fields with `required` are mandatory

Comment: @Sridhar User error on my part, haha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User error on my part, I thought there was something wrong with everything except my forgetfulness. Long story short, I added a new partial template to my project and was getting the email via `input[type=email]`. The partial added a second one so the email parameter was never received by the backend.

Whoops.